# "...measures must be taken to..." VS "...measures have to be taken to..."

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I must rewrite the follwing passage into passive:

> They have to take new measures to prevent more flooding.

We use must when "it's our intention" and "have to" - when we can do nothing with the task or current situation and someone else is making the decision for us.

Since that, it would be better to say:

> New measures must be taken to prevent more flooding.

instead of:

> New measures have to be taken to prevent more flooding.

Comment: That distinction between **must** and **have to** doesn't always hold true.  *I must take this medication. I have to take this medication* express the same idea.  Both of your flood measures examples are OK.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, what are the conditions the choise depends on?

Comment: In my AmE dialect, you could use them interchangeably and never be wrong. You would simply sound a tad more formal than the situation might require if you used **must**, but only in certain circumstances. Again, in my AmE dialect, in conversation,  **have to** is preferred for relatively minor tasks that need to get done, and **must** is preferred for more important obligations that  need to be met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most situations it seems that the two (must/have to) are interchangeable, but if splitting hairs there is a difference in consequences (in must cases the consequence being more dire). https://www.grammarbank.com/must-have-has-to.html

In your specific question, when I give my students passive voice exercises I generally expect them to use the same verbs. I would say that being that have to is used in the original sentence, it is probably best to continue it in your answer.